# angularjs old value and new value in ng-change with also empty selection

Tags: angularjs

There are so many examples with old value and new value tracking on the change event, but the problem I am facing is I would like to trace when I select the empty option. Please check below example

```
<select  ng-model="col" ng-change="filters.selName(col, '{{col}}');">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in filters.options" value="{{option.value}}">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

"{{col}}" holds my previous old data if I chose empty select..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use to get previous value is a bit `hacky` and not recommended. A more clear approach would be to use another variable to keep the previously selected value like this:

```
<select ng-model="col" ng-change="filters.selName(col)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in filters.options" value="{{option.value}}">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

```
$scope.previousSel;
$scope.filters.selName = function(col) {   
     $scope.previousSel = col;
}
```

Check a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1n30hrze/14/)